# How to record only the header info when using `tcpdump`

Tags: networking, command-line, monitoring, tcpdump

When running the following command

`tcpdump -i deviceName 'host 1.2.3.4' -q -w /mypath/dump.pcap`

the dump file contains a huge amount of data because there's a lot of traffic.  However, I only need to save the header details of each packet, not the entire contents.  I tried using the `-q` switch (for "quiet") but that's not helping.

I need Time, Source, Destination, Protocol and Length.  I do not need any of the other information, and especially not the full contents of each packet.

If there's a way to ignore the contents and only write the header details to disk so as to save space?  I'm getting to over a GB in a matter of minutes :(

I've seen many questions about how to *increase* the amount of data saved, but nothing for *reducing* it.  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: See also [How do I use tcpdump to capture all traffic headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/253613/tcpdump-how-do-i-use-it-to-capture-all-traffic-headers).

Comment: See option `-s snaplen` or `--snapshot-length=snaplen`. See https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html. They seem to have increased the default. (I remember that in old times I often had to increase the value which was less than 100 at this time.)

Comment: I was under the impression that snaplen would only record information regarding packets below a certain size, not that it would limit what was saved to file.  I'll take a look and get back to you.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Local login or remote ssh session?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm running the commands using PuTTY, if I'm honest I don't know what protocol that is, probably SCP, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in the same situation and I solved it by adding -s 96

Comment: Thanks Zatarra, adding this really simple bit sorted it out for me.  I still get all the info I need but without the nasty overhead.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need Time, Source, Destination, Protocol.
It work for me using

```
tcpdump -i $INTERFACE -n -s 50
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS